# Do Qur'an verse counts correspond to the moon landing date and take-off time from the surface of moon?

Tags: islam, moon, quran

There are claims that not just the event itself, but the time of the first moon landing coincided with a prophecy about the moon in the Qur'an.

This page [claims](http://www.quranmiracles.com/2011/03/the-date-of-the-landing-on-the-moon/) a match with the year 1969:

> One of the most important among the signs is in the first verse of
>   the sura “The Moon” (Qamar). The number of verses to be counted from
>   this verse to the end of the Quran is 1389. The year 1389 in the
>   Muslim calendar corresponds to the year 1969 in the Gregorian
>   calendar. And the year 1969 was the year when man landed on the moon
>   for the first time.

[Another](http://www.islamawareness.net/Prophecies/hidden.html) one claims a match with the exact time of take-off from the moon:

> A very interesting prophecy relates to the moon landing (which
>   occurred in 1969), is it possible The Quran predicted this? Well,
>   judge for yourself by considering the following information – Chapter
>   54 of The Quran is entitled “The Moon” and starts right away by giving
>   us news about the splitting of the moon as a sign that the end of the
>   world is drawing close.
>
> “The moon has split and the hour has drawn closer” (The Quran, 54:1)
>
> When did the prophecy come to pass?
>
> To answer that, one must keep the prophecy in mind: “The moon has
>   split.” This is a metaphor. Parts of the moon have left its surface.
>   They no longer are part of the moon. So, the prophecy does not refer
>   to the landing on the moon or to the first step made by Neil Armstrong
>   but to the fact that Armstrong and Aldrin collected 21 kilograms of
>   lunar rocks to bring back to earth. The prophecy was fulfilled at the
>   very moment the astronauts left the moon in the lunar module
>   containing 21 kilograms of rocks that had belonged to the moon. This
>   can be confirmed by checking the definition of “split” in any
>   dictionary, among the definitions given by Dictionary.com are – “to
>   divide, disunite, separate”
>
> The date this prophecy came to pass was on July 21 1969. The moment
>   the prophecy was fulfilled is confirmed by the hour of departure of
>   the lunar module, which left the lunar surface at 17:54:1 (Universal
>   Time) or 1:54:1 (EDT) and as you have seen above, verse [54:1] is the
>   verse that deals with the prophecy.
>
> Still not convinced? Lets read the following verses after (54:1) –
>
> “The moon has split and the hour has drawn closer. Then they saw a
>   great miracle; but they turned away and said, “Old magic.” They
>   disbelieved, followed their opinions, and adhered to their old
>   traditions.” (The Quran, from 54:1 to 54:3)
>
> Here, the author of The Quran specifically states – “the moon has
>   split”, then people will see “a great miracle”, yet they still
>   “disbelieved”. Could the “great miracle” be the fulfillment of
>   prophecy?

Is there any truth behind those claims? Did the verse numbers and the moon landing really line up this way?

@IMSoP made a valid objection in the comments. 
Here's a Qur'an from 1649: https://archive.org/details/alcoranofmahomet00dury.
The Chapter of the Moon is at 54. The rest of the order seems same too. Though I haven't checked and compared all of them. Feel free to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure what we can check here. Even if the facts about the verse numbering were true, whether or not these constitute a prophecy or a coincidence is a matter of opinion.

Comment: "I'm not sure what we can check here." The verse count and the take-off time perhaps ?

Comment: Who writes clock seconds without a leading zero, ever o.O

Comment: @StarWeaver Does it really matter though ? It's still read as 1 second, no?

Comment: How acceptable is numerology in Islam? I have a feeling it's highly associated with occultism, much like in Judaism and Christianity.

Comment: "How acceptable is numerology in Islam?". I suppose it is acceptable to some Muslims and perhaps not acceptable to some another. There's no such thing as priesthood/clergy in Islam. So you can't answer it like "Catholic Church says ..." etc. Either way, it is not related with the claim.

Comment: With an implicit, rather than explicit, prophecy like this date and time, how would we know the difference between it getting the year right, or missing by one? That depends on if you count the verse in question or not when counting to the end of the Quran. Or what if it got it completely wrong, because the years were supposed to be counted from the beginning of the Quran, instead? If the idea is "we don't know in advance what it means, until we find a coincidence to match to it", then Shakespeare might be just as prophetic, in that limited sense.

Comment: I think your point is valid. "That depends on if you count the verse in question or not when counting to the end of the Quran". Right, this only addresses the first claim though. The second one still stands.

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if your question itself asked if the relevant numbers in the Quran and the times related to the lunar landing do indeed match, rather than asking about "prediction"? Or do you want answers to say if this is a normal way of understanding Quranic prophesies?

Comment: I think my question is clear as you seem to have understand what I asked for. I used the word "prediction" because that's what the sources claim.

Comment: There are essentially 2 claims in my question. First one claims that Qur'an predicted moon landing date second one claims that Qur'an predicted the take-off time of astronauts. Your statement is a valid argument against the first one as I said before.

Comment: "Do you want to know, assuming the numbers do indeed line up". Yes, exactly.

Comment: No, I'm not interested in "what the general Muslim community thinks". Just to see if numbers match up. i.e If there are really 1389 verses from that chapter to the end of the Qur'an and if it really corresponds to 1969 in Gregorian calendar etc.

Comment: Yeah that's entirely fine. Feel free to edit my question as well.

Comment: A prediction is only valid if it's made BEFORE the event comes to pass. If nobody said "the moon landing will happen in 1969" or something equivalent, it's not a prediction. Tell me, did a sect of Muslims go, "Yeah, saw that coming a mile off"? It's easy to connect the dots after the event and say, "Hey, the Qur'an says something similar!" But did those dots connect before the event?

Comment: Technically, it is made by Quran which is written by some 1,4k years ago. It is the people who discover it later. However, I am interested in if numbers really match. Whether it's a coincidence or a prophecy is up to you. I don't care about that though.

Comment: SpiderRico: just curious, how would you respond to a question "Did Qur'an *incorrectly* predict moon landing date?", that was based on the number of verses between the *start* of the book and this chapter *not* matching the year of the moon landing? Why is the number of verses after this chapter a prediction, and not the number of verses before it?

Comment: One line of evidence that would invalidate these claims is anything demonstrating changes in the composition or order of the Quran, since this would change both variables alleged to encode the prophecy. Apparently, some Islamic scholars claim it is complete and unchanged from Mohammed's own recitation, but there is evidence to the contrary. Perhaps somebody could frame an answer using the references in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Quran

Comment: @IMSoP See: https://archive.org/details/alcoranofmahomet00dury. The Alcoran of Mahomet : translated out of Arabique into French. From 1649. Has the same ordering of surahs.

Comment: @user568458 I see your point and I think it is a valid one. However, I just used the word "predict" because sources did so. Please don't focus on it too much. As now the edited question clearly asks that whether numbers match or not.

Comment: @SpiderRico The Quran is claimed to date from the *7th* century, so a manuscript from the *17th* isn't particularly relevant. Have a look at the Wikipedia article I linked.

Comment: @IMSoP Does it really matter ? There was  a Qur'an with the same ordering of surahs much before 1969.  Sure, there might have been a Qur'an with different ordering surahs at some point in history. In fact, you can make one by yourself right now. But the claim is made on a Qur'an with this particular order and my question is about if this "prophecy" holds for this Qur'an. If there were no Qur'an with the same ordering of surahs before moon landing, then I guess it would have been safe to say that this "prophecy" was forged.

Comment: @SpiderRico I was not claiming it showed the prophecy to be forged after the fact, but that if the number of surahs and verses is different in different editions, then there are different "predictions" for the moon landing. The claim of "prophecy" relies on the order being a fixed and fundamental aspect of the Qur'an, rather than an artefact of some particular reorganisation. If you picked one popular edition, you might be able to make further alignments with page numbers, the first word on a page, etc, but this wouldn't be "the Qur'an" making the alignments.

Comment: @IMSoP Again, you're more or less right. But as I said above "But the claim is made on a Qur'an with this particular order and my question is about if this "prophecy" holds for this Qur'an". And almost everyone will understand the Qur'an with this ordering when Qur'an is mentioned. Google Qur'an and check few of the orderings. So, I guess -at least to me- it makes sense that claim is made with on the most popular version(if not the only one). As I said though, you're not entirely wrong.

Comment: @SpiderRico You are gradually reducing the scope of the question to the point where it is meaningless. It's like watching a conjuror perform a card trick and asking only "did they pick out the right card?" If the answer is yes, do you conclude that the conjuror is psychic? Or worse, watching a video of a conjuror, and saying you don't care if they recorded 52 different versions so they were guaranteed of the right answer.

Comment: @IMSoP Fair enough. It seems you're pondering over small matters anyway. I think the question is clear and really what I ask is independent of what you say. Again, all I'm saying is: "the claim is made on a Qur'an with this particular order and my question is about if this "prophecy" holds for this Qur'an". I would love to reword my question but there is no such thing as KJV of Qur'an etc. So, Qur'an = Qur'an with this ordering from a practical point of view.

Comment: @SpiderRico If you take away the context which you want us to ignore, plus trivially checkable things like "is there a chapter of the Qu'ran headed The Moon?" and "is 1389 the Muslim name for AD 1969?", then the question becomes: "a) Are there 1389 verses after verse 54:1 in a modern edition of the Qu'ran? b) Did Apollo 11 take off at 54 minutes and 1 second past the hour?" Even those questions, while harder to research, are fairly trivial facts. If you edited the question down to those two sentences, would it still be interesting?

Comment: Incidentally, a smell that the writer of your second article hasn't done much research is them consulting an *English* dictionary, when discussing an *Arabic* text. Unless the claim is, even more tenuously, that *the English translation of the Qu'ran* makes the prophecy.

Comment: Tons of materials get ejected every year from the Moon due to impacts with meteorites. Those aren't considered splits? In any case, this question should have no place in [skeptics.se]. There is no way to determine if Qur'an does have any predictions about moon landing. It's a matter of whether or not once agrees with someone's interpretation of a particular Sura, and that solely depends on ones own opinion. **Please vote to close this**. I would, if I had close votes.

Comment: I’d suggest a competition: Can we find for each of the numbers from 1 to 2000 an explanation how the Quran predicted that number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indeed, one can verify that the number of verses counted excluding the first one are exactly 1389. You can verify this using any [online quran](http://quran.com).

Also, the year 1389 in islamic calendar happens to be the year 1969. This can be verified using any [online converter](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1389+islamic+to+gregorian&x=0&y=0)

However, this is merely a coincidence:

1) There is no clear evidence that the chapters of Quran were numbered at the time of the prophet Mohammed. At his time people used chapter names (it is actually easier to use names than numbers).
In fact, the Quran was not assembled into a book until after the death of Mohammad; at his time people used to memorize the Quran. See: [The origin of the Quran](http://www.whyislam.org/the-origin-of-the-quran)

2) The Quran verse at hand talks about an incident [well known by many muslims](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_the_moon). It uses the past tense. The writer of the second claim tries to hide this:

> Here, the author of The Quran specifically states – “the moon has split”, then people **will see** “a great miracle”, yet they still “disbelieved”

However, if you read the actual text, it is written in the past tense:

> The moon has split and the hour has drawn closer. Then **they saw a great miracle**; but they turned away and said, “Old magic.” They disbelieved, followed their opinions, and adhered to their old traditions.” (The Quran, from 54:1 to 54:3)

Comment: "However, if you read the actual text, it is written in the past tense". Abdel Haleem's note on this verse: One of the signs of the Day of Judgement. The Arabic uses the past tense, as if that
Day were already here, to help the reader/listener imagine how it will be. Some traditional
commentators hold the view that this describes an actual event at the time of the
Prophet, but it clearly refers to the end of the world: cf. the same expression with
reference to the sky, 55: 37; 84: 1.

Comment: @mhmd I'm not sure where you got this translation from but it's far from accurate (Arabic is my mother tongue). Quoting from the same website you referenced (quran.com), the translation is: _"The Hour has come near, and the moon has split [in two]. **And if they see a miracle**, they turn away and say, 'Passing magic.'"_ (54:1 to 54:2) - Note: I'm _only_ commenting on the accuracy of the translation here; I'm _**not**_ saying that the claim presented in the question is valid.

Comment: @Ahmed thanks for your comment. The last paragraph is taken from the above text and not from quran.com or any other source. Its purpose is only to show the contradiction the writer has in his own post. But, you are right, the translation itself is also incorrect so thats an additional point against the op.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this:

Some people are asking why count from 54:1 to the end and not from the beginning, because chapter 54 is called the moon or [Al-Qamar](https://quran.com/54?startingVerse=1) in Arabic, and the last chapter 114 is called Mankind/the men or [An-naas](https://quran.com/an-nas) in Arabic.

Also why from exactly 54:1 onwards, because the last word in the Arabic Quran for 54:1 is the "moon", and the last word of the last verse of chapter 114 is "men".  This can be confirmed by using the same links I attached in the last paragraph: by clicking on the Arabic writing found above the English translated verse - Note: Arabic is read from right to left, so to view the last word for verses 54:1 & 114:6 would be the left-most word.

Also, the French copy is one of many that have the same chapter order. So to propose that this was ordered after would be disingenuous. Besides, if the chapters were re-arranged, it would break multiple other miracles of the Qur'ans structure. Take for example the ring composition, or miracle 19. Besides the time miracle, if you consider the other Quranic miracles/signs, I think it would be fair to say that a time prediction was intentional and not a coincidence. Here's an explanation of the Qur'an structure by [Dr. Shabbir ally](https://youtu.be/wxwvIbmuhhI) & [miracle 19](https://www.19miracle.org/).

Also, there was around [200](http://christianityinview.com/religion-statistics.html) million Muslims at 1900, also, the Qur'an is the most [memorised](https://www.google.com/search?q=most%20memorised%20book&oq=most%20memorised%20book%20&aqs=chrome..69i57.7163j0j7&client=ms-android-oneplus&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) book in the world since according to Muslims, it has the highest reward in paradise. One of the criticism of the other religious texts proposed by the [Qur'an](https://quran.com/en/al-baqarah/79)(2:79) is its lack of preservation/distortion hence why Muslims historically were super focused on [preserving](https://onepathnetwork.com/the-history-of-the-preservation-of-the-quran/) the Qur'an and other books such as the [Greek texts](https://www.openculture.com/2017/06/how-arabic-translators-helped-preserve-greek-philosophy-and-the-classical-tradition.html). Also, the Qur'an is fully read in congregation from start to finish throughout the month of Ramadan, this is called [taraweeh](https://www.google.com/search?q=taraweeh&oq=taraweeh&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l7.1617j0j9&client=ms-android-oneplus&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) prayer which takes about 1-2 hours at night for about 30 days.

54:3 They reject (the warning) and follow their (own) lusts but every matter has its appointed time.
54:4 There have already come to them Recitals wherein there is (enough) to check (them),
54:5 Mature wisdom;- but (the preaching of) Warners profits them not.

- My mention of these verses was referring to the Quranic challenge to the reader, that the verses are out there ready to be checked and measured. Every prophet throughout time came with a message, and a proof of prophethood, i.e. splitting the sea, curing the blind etc. But these were for its people at a specific time and place since you weren't their to see it, and for prophet Muhammad, pbuh, who's considered the last prophet from a line of prophets, one of the proofs of prophethood was the Qur'an itself which is proof for [all](https://www.noorulislam.org.uk/a-messenger-for-all-mankind/) of mankind till the end of time, hence the various [miracles](https://www.miracles-of-quran.com/) found throughout the Qur'an.
- Also to note: this is by the Indian-british [Yusuf Ali](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdullah_Yusuf_Ali)(1872-1953) english translation of the Qur'an, which is one the most popular English translations out there today which was written prior to 1969.

For more maths miracles, going into the specifics by demonstration, the [DNA](https://youtu.be/LwlBp1SEieo) structure found in the Qur'an might interest you, see this playlist on [YouTube](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiU47G2ulReebWVECXb1nz2uQi5ihpKOF).

Comment: Welcome Reg Lee. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. You'll find that we like to look rather more deeply into the source material and provide linked references. It's not clear what your answer is saying much of the time, but it does seem to be relying on an interpretation rather than cited evidence. (Such as the re-numbering event or the tenses of the quoted statements not fitting with your interpretation). Your post would also have benefited from correct formatting, the use of the quote function etc..

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thanks for the comment, I wouldn't have known if you didn't mention since this was my first time posting on this site

Comment: Nice edit, I'll upvote. Enjoy the site.